# Empty string from .php script on HTTP response

Tags: php, angularjs, http, nginx

I have a web app running on an `Nginx` server and I'm having problems with an `HTTP` request.

I'm using `PHP` on the server and `AngularJS` for the frontend.

I'm sending an `HTTP POST` request to the server to fetch some data from the database:

```
$http.post("backend/get_questions.php", { team_id: $scope.user.team_id, user_id: $scope.user.user_id, user_type: $scope.user.user_type })
       .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response.data.success){
               $scope.questions = response.data.questions.slice();
            } else {
               alert(response.data.message);
            }
                
})
```

On the `get_questions.php` script I connect to the database using `PDO` and I fetch the results from the *questions* table. Then I return the data to the client:

```
$questions = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($questions) > 0){
    $response = array("success" => true, "message" => "Data successfully retrieved", "questions" => $questions);
} else {
    $response = array("success" => false, "message" => "There are no records related to the specified team.");
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

This is the approach I used on every other HTTP request, but I only have problems with this one. The server returns an empty string on the data property of the response object.

```
{
  "data": "",
  "status": 200,
  "config": {
    "method": "POST",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "url": "backend/get_questions.php",
    "data": {
      "team_id": 4,
      "user_id": "professor@professor.com",
      "user_type": "professor"
    },
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    }
  },
  "statusText": "OK",
  "xhrStatus": "complete"
}
```

I tried removing the `"questions"` key from the associative array to see if that was causing the issue, and indeed that was it. If I don't include the data fetched from the database, the HTTP response comes out as normal. I don't get it because on the other HTTP requests that I send to the server I don't get this type of problem.

Any ideas what might cause this?

***Update:** I used the *json_last_error_msg()* function and I got this error:

```
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in the network tab using your browser's builtin developer tools?

Comment: Have you tried using `print_r($questions); die;` before the if statements?

Comment: @Adi Yes, I forgot to mention that. The array has multiple elements and gets printed normally. I think it might be a problem with the `json_encode` function. Like, for some reason it can't encode the resulting array.

Comment: so it means the data you are getting from database is not utf-8 encoded